# Is there a logic to formalize the concept of "understanding"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, modal-logic, nonclassical-logic

The question may seem little bit weird given that philosophers have been struggling to have a full grasp on the concept of "understanding".

But I'm wondering if there are any logics (modal-based or others) to formalize the following statement:

"agent A understands the proposition p" or "agent A understands that the proposition p is true"

Where "understands" could be considered as a modal operator like the epistemic modal operator "agent A knows p".

Thank you,

Comment: Is [justification](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-justification/) close enough to understanding?

Comment: Did you think about a possible assiomatization of this kind of operator?
What can be the implication of the understanding?
It seems a binary relation $\mathfrak U \subset \Bbb A \times P$ where $A \mathfrak U \phi$ means *"A understands the proposition p"*... it need two kinds of elements , the agents ($\Bbb A$) and the propostions ($ P$). Because I don't think that a statement $\phi$ can understand another statement $\varphi$.

Comment: Maybe this kind of logic is related to an assiomatization of the awareness, because if the agent-type elements are in some way "aware" they can "understand" something. Maybe you should look for integrated information theory.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory

Comment: @ChrisCulter: I think it's more related to explanation than justification. Although, I can see a fine line between them, you may justify a proposition "p" by providing the evidences {e1,...,en} but it won't make any sense to me if I don't understand the evidences and their link to the proposition "p". 
About explanation and its relation to understanding, I would say I understand something if I have an access to it's explanation.
Thus,I would say an agent understands a proposition "p" if she knows an explanation of "p".

Comment: @MphLee: first, thanks for your answer. answering your first comment,no I have thought about that. Given the importance of this concept I thought that there must have been work done on this subject. Anyway, understanding is indeed an binary relation between an agent and things to be understood. Away from syntax, what is the underlying semantics of such sentence. For instance, the semantics of "agent knows that p is true" is based on the concept of epistemic indistinguishability.

Comment: @MphLee: the question to be asked, if I'm aware of p does this mean I understand p ? I think this is not accurate, for example I can be aware of "the sun rises from west" but I can't understand why.

Comment: @Abdallah Yes, I'm not expert at all in this field but it fasinates me so much! I was not thinking that the relations *"A understands p"* is equivalent to *"A is aware of p"* but I tought that there is a link, in the same way as there is a link with the "explaination" concept as you noted.

Comment: @MphLee: yes it might be, I'll look at it deeply, I may get lucky and find something :). thanks.

Comment: You can see Georg Henrik von Wright, [Explanation and Understanding](https://books.google.it/books?id=33wCi2bg5x0C&pg=frontcover) (1971), but it is a book "less involved" with modal logic comparing with others von Wright's ones.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: thanks for the link, I'll take a look at it. Other comments are very welcomed.

Comment: I think this question belongs to the field of formal philosophy, and not in mathematics. As such, I am voting to close (1.5 years later!) Despite this, I want to stress I find it a very interesting question.